Creation of user with python of LDAP fails
For unit testing (and learning) purposes, I want to assert that users are created in ldap. Configuration data to connect to LDAP server and testing data are stored in a single json file and read by python script.
Running the python script, The first user in the json file is created, but the second is not and I get this error:
Error: ERROR: User 'uid=user.2,ou=identity,o=example.com' was not created: noSuchObject.
The user is not created in LDAP after verification.
json file
  {
         "baseDN":"o=example.com",
         "bindDN":"cn=Directory Manager",
         "bindPassword":"xxxx",
         "ldap_url_primary":"<server_address>",
         "users": [
             {
               "dn": "uid=user.1,ou=identity,o=example.com",
               "user_attributes":
                {
                   "objectClass": ["top","organizationalPerson","inetOrgPerson"],
                   "uid": "user.1",
                   "o": "example.com",
                }
              },
              {
               "dn": "uid=user.2,ou=identity,o=example.com",
               "user_attributes":
                {
                  "objectClass": ["top","organizationalPerson","inetOrgPerson"],
                  "uid": "user.2",
                  "o": "example.com",
                }
              }
            ]
        }


python script
def check_user_existence(bindDN, bindPassword, uid, ldap_url, baseDN):
    server = Server(ldap_url)
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = Connection(server, bindDN, bindPassword)
        conn.open()
        conn.bind()

        conn.search(search_base=baseDN,
             search_filter='(uid={})'.format(uid),
             search_scope=SUBTREE,
             attributes=['uid'])
        if len(conn.entries) > 0:
           return True
        else:
           return False
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e )
        return False
    conn.unbind()

def create_user(bindDN, bindPassword, ldap_url, baseDN, user_dn,user_attributes):
    server = Server(ldap_url)
    conn = None
    try:
       conn = Connection(server, bindDN, bindPassword)
       conn.open()
       conn.bind()
       result = conn.add(user_dn, attributes=user_attributes)
       conn.search(search_base=user_dn,
             search_filter='(objectClass=*)',
             search_scope=SUBTREE,
             attributes=['*'])
       if result:
          print(f"User {user_dn} created successfully")
       else:
           msg = "ERROR: User '{0}' was not created: {1}".format(
                user_dn, conn.result.get("description"))
           raise Exception(msg)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
    conn.unbind()

def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestLDAP('test_user_created'))
    return suite

class TestLDAP(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       try:
           with open("values.json", 'r') as file:
              content = json.load(file)
           self.uid_list = content["uid"]
           self.bindDN = content["bindDN"]
           self.baseDN = content["baseDN"]
           self.bindPassword = content["bindPassword"]
           self.ldap_url = content["ldap_url_primary"]
           self.users = content["users"]
       except IOError as e:
           return f"Error: An IOError occurred. {e}"

    def test_user_created(self):
        for user in self.users:
           create_user(self.bindDN, self.bindPassword, self.ldap_url, self.baseDN, user["dn"], user["user_attributes"])
           self.assertTrue(check_user_existence(self.bindDN, self.bindPassword,user["user_attributes"]["uid"],self.ldap_url, self.baseDN),"uid {} created".format(user["dn"]))


if __name__ == '__main__':

  runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
  runner.run(suite())


There aren't difference between user.1 and user.2 at least in your example code. It is possible that with the real data something in user.2 is not correct.
